# How to return more than one search results by Wikipedia API?

Tags: wikipedia-api

I'm trying to fetch results using Wikipedia API. My query is below. I want to fetch 5 results on searched topic. Like if I search *"India"* it should return 5 search results on India, with 2-3 sentences on each result. I'm trying to limit search results with `exlimit` but it is not working.

```
 https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=india&format=jsonfm&prop=extracts&exintro=true&exlimit=5&exsentences=3
```

This query is returning only one result. I want 10 such results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `action=query&titles=india` you will get exactly the [India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India) Wikipedia page. For your case you need to use [search](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bsearch) option:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=india&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=5&prop=extracts&exchars=200&exlimit=max&explaintext=1&exintro=1
```

where `gsrlimit=5` is how many results to be returned and `exchars=200` is how many characters to be taken from each result.